# Deactivate WLAN chip on a Pi2

Tags: wireless, raspberrypi

I need to use a 5GHz supporting USB-WLAN-Stick on a RasperryPi 3 Model B, v1.2. Because of that I need to deactivate the on-board-WLAN-device.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you quite certain that the Pi *2* has an internal wifi chip? I thought that the Pi 3 was the first generation with internal wifi.

Comment: No WiFi in a Raspberry Pi 2 as per https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-2-model-b/ so please confirm what you have.  Please click [edit] and confirm what you have. If you have a 2 or 2B, well, there's no WiFi to worry about conflicting with your USB WiFi adapter.